# SortedDictionary (C#)- change value

Tags: c#, .net, collections, sorteddictionary

In a SortedDictionary  is it possible to *change* the value of an item ?

Comment: Yes, but does that mess up the sort?

Comment: Nope. It's sorted by keys, not values.

Comment: @hrs, do you perhaps mean: change the Key?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, why not?

```
sortedDictionary[key] = newValue;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just use the indexer like this (in C#):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SortedDictionary<int, string> map = 
            new SortedDictionary<int, string>();
        map[1] = "Kevin Hazzard";
        Console.WriteLine( map[1] );
        map[1] = "W. Kevin Hazzard";
        Console.WriteLine( map[1] );
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change values and keys, by definition keys are sorted (when adding)

To change a key, store value in a temp, remove the key, and Add the new key with the temp value.